# Node.js -searching for specific string in txt files

Tags: node.js

I am trying to print all Txt files full path ,which contains a specific string .
How can i achive this with node js through the cmd?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create file one or two file containing strings.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
// check if you not passed correct commands
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log("USAGE: node " + " search" + " [EXT]" + " [TEXT]");
  process.exit(1);
}

function searchInTxtFiles(ext, str) {
  // root directory
  const dirPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
  // read all the files and filter those files which match with targeted extension like .txt
  const fileLists = fs
    .readdirSync(dirPath)
    .filter(e => path.extname(e).toLowerCase() === "." + ext);
    // loop thru the fileLists
  return fileLists.map(d => {
    return fs.readFile(d, function(err, content) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // check if the file content has the string that passed from terminal
      if (content.indexOf(str) > -1) {
        console.log(__dirname + "\\" + d);
      } else {
        console.log("No file was found");
      }
    });
  });
}

searchInTxtFiles(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
// input:  node index.js txt lorem
// output: /readfile/data.txt
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more details and comments?

Comment: I updated this. I hope now it's more clear than before